# Calculus- Derivatives, using the Formal Definition (Tangent Lines)

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent line to the graph of $y=x-x^2$ at the indicated point, $(-2,-6)$
I started but I got stuck, the answer options are $y=-3x+4, y=-5x+4, y=5x+4,$ and $ y=-3x-4.$

Comment: $y'(-2)=5$, so there is only one choice ...

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of your function is $1-2x$. This is also the slope of your tangent line. So plugging in you will get $1-2(-2)=5$. Therefore the slope of the tangent line is $5$. Now you have the slope of the tangent line, you need to find the $y$ intercept. This is done by setting $y=5x+b$. Plug in the coordinates from your given point, and you will see what the $y$-intercept must be for the tangent line.